# exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated in flink job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I am doing joining in flink and I am getting `exceeded the 80 characters length limit and was truncated.`

```
Table tr = tableEnv.sqlQuery("select " +
            " coalesce(a.id, b.id) id," +
            " coalesce(a.item, b.item) item," +
            " a.amount as revenue," +
            " b.amount as profit" +
            " from " +
            " (select * from tableA" +
            " where type='revenue') a" +
            " full outer join " +
            " (select * from tableA" +
            " where type='profit') b" +
            " on a.id=b.id, a.item=b.item");
```

I am not sure how to resolve this. Is there any limit of character in joining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are seeing this warning:

```
The operator name {} exceeded the {} characters length limit and was truncated.
```

You can safely ignore this. This just means that label you see in the web UI won't show the complete SQL join.